# JS Function work just on the browser console

Tags: javascript

I have the following function.

```
function loadSplides() {
    let elms = document.querySelectorAll('.splide');
    console.log("document.querySelectorAll('.splide') JS COMMAND")
    console.log(elms)
    for ( let i = 0; i < elms.length; i++ ) {
        console.log('loop')
        console.log("LOOP", i)
        new Splide( elms[i], {
            type: 'loop',
            fixedHeight: '20rem',
            cover: true,
        } ).mount();
    }
}


$(document).ready(() => {
    $('#index').remove()

    const sponsors = async () => {requestSponsors()}
    sponsors().then(() => {loadSplides()})
})
```

The `elms` return an empty array, but whe I do this same command `document.querySelectorAll('.splide');` on the browser console, the return is an array with 5 elements

[image]

Comment: Are those elements loaded into the DOM dynamically?  For example, if they're created by `requestSponsors()` then I wouldn't expect them to be loaded yet when this executes since that operation isn't awaited.

Comment: Yes they are, but I am running `requestSponsors()` inside an async(), and using then to run the `laodSplides()`, that should wait to all elements be created right?

Comment: What does `requestSponsors` return? Just putting it in an `async` function won't make the function wait for whatever `requestSponsors` is doing. The fix might be as easy as changing the the code to `requestSponsors().then(...)`.

Comment: May be log from both methods and see if they are loaded in dom before the place you expect it to execute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those elements appear to be loaded dynamically.  Likely by `requestSponsors()`?  If that's the case then you'll need to await that operation.  **Assuming it returns a `Promise`**, currently its resulting `Promise` is being lost.  You can either `await` it directly in your `async` function:

```
const sponsors = async () => {await requestSponsors()}
```

Or return the resulting `Promise` from the function, either by removing the curly braces:

```
const sponsors = async () => requestSponsors()
```

or by explicitly returning:

```
const sponsors = async () => {return requestSponsors()}
```

---

If `requestSponsors()` *doesn't* return a `Promise` then you'll need to examine and possibly modify it to see how its asynchronous operation (loading these elements, possibly from an AJAX operation?) can be awaited.

Comment: Yeah, i moved that piece of code to my ajax and worked, but that explanation was really god, thx man.